# Libraries available for native modules

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Applications for Android devices are written in Java. I also know of the existence of the NDK (Native Development Kit).

I have a library written in C++ that uses:

- stl containers
- c++ i/o (streams etc..)
- memory allocation/deallocation using new etc...

Are all this things available to the programmer that want to use the NDK for C++ development?

I am confident that memory alloc and stl are there, but what about I/O from files? Can i use istream/ostream? I ask because i have programmed apps on Symbian and i had to use RFile and other classes (there was no support for fopen/fread etc).

Comment: I'm not confident enough with the subject to post this as an answer, but you should look into the JNI to interface Java programs to C++. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, low level I/O is possible. fopen/fread are available from the first NDK release.
istream/ostream are available since NDK r5 when STLport and GNU stl were added.